# Custom keyboard view in android

Tags: android, keyboard, customization

I'm developing a custom Android keyboard. I started to develop my keyboard, based on [this](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/create-a-custom-keyboard-on-android--cms-22615) tutorial. However, I want my keyboard to have customized view instead of the default keyboard view. To be specific, I want to use listview to select words. Is this possible?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You don't have to use the KeyboardView widget.. just put whatever views you want into the keyboard.xml layout file.

I haven't tried using listviews, but I know that normal layouts/buttons/imageviews/textviews work fine.

Comment: Oh, so how do I define keys to be used for OnKeyboardActionListener ?

Comment: You wouldn't use that class... your custom view would listen for button events (or listview events in your case) and then call methods on the ```InputConnection``` itself.

Comment: Thanks and sorry for the late reply. I put this project on a hold for a while. I am still confused. So the class that renders this layout should extend InputConnection only? and how to I render this as a keyboard?

Comment: You can inflate any layout you want for the keyboard UI.  Here's the docs on it: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/text/creating-input-method.html#IMEUI