# Custom keyboard focus issue using Remote

Tags: android, keyboard, android-tv

I am creating app for AndroidTV and my requirement is to create a custom onscreen keyboard. I created a Keyboard using **KyboardView** and I am getting keyboard wrapped in **RelativeLayout**. I am not able to focus on the keys using DPAD Remote. Below is my code -

**Activity**

```
KeyboardView keyboardView = (KeyboardView) view.findViewById(R.id.keyboardView);
keyboardView.setKeyboard(new Keyboard(getActivity(),R.xml.keyboard_qwerty));
keyboardView.setPreviewEnabled(false);
keyboardView.setOnKeyboardActionListener(new KeyboardView.OnKeyboardActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPress(int primaryCode) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onRelease(int primaryCode) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onKey(int primaryCode, int[] keyCodes) {
            Log.e(TAG, "#onkey - "+primaryCode);
        }

        @Override
        public void onText(CharSequence text) {
            YuppLog.e(TAG, "#text - "+text);

        }

        @Override
        public void swipeLeft() {

        }

        @Override
        public void swipeRight() {

        }

        @Override
        public void swipeDown() {

        }

        @Override
        public void swipeUp() {

        }
    });
```

**keyboard_qwertty**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Keyboard xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:keyHeight="7.5%p"
android:horizontalGap="0.3%p"
android:verticalGap="0.5%p"
android:keyWidth="10%p">
<Row>
    <Key
        android:codes="49"
        android:keyEdgeFlags="left"
        android:keyLabel="1" />
    <Key
        android:codes="50"
        android:keyLabel="2" />
    <Key
        android:codes="51"
        android:keyLabel="3" />
    <Key
        android:codes="52"
        android:keyLabel="4" />
    <Key
        android:codes="53"
        android:keyLabel="5" />
    <Key
        android:codes="54"
        android:keyLabel="6" />
    <Key
        android:codes="55"
        android:keyLabel="7" />
    <Key
        android:codes="56"
        android:keyLabel="8" />
    <Key
        android:codes="57"
        android:keyLabel="9" />
    <Key
        android:codes="48"
        android:keyEdgeFlags="right"
        android:keyLabel="0" />
</Row>
<Row>
    <Key
        android:codes="113"
        android:keyEdgeFlags="left"
        android:keyLabel="q" />
    <Key
        android:codes="119"
        android:keyLabel="w" />
    <Key
        android:codes="101"
        android:keyLabel="e" />
    <Key
        android:codes="114"
        android:keyLabel="r" />
    <Key
        android:codes="116"
        android:keyLabel="t" />
    <Key
        android:codes="121"
        android:keyLabel="y" />
    <Key
        android:codes="117"
        android:keyLabel="u" />
    <Key
        android:codes="105"
        android:keyLabel="i" />
    <Key
        android:codes="111"
        android:keyLabel="o" />
    <Key
        android:codes="112"
        android:keyEdgeFlags="right"
        android:keyLabel="p" />
</Row>
<Row>
    <Key
        android:codes="97"
        android:keyEdgeFlags="left"
        android:keyLabel="a" />
    <Key
        android:codes="115"
        android:keyLabel="s" />
    <Key
        android:codes="100"
        android:keyLabel="d" />
    <Key
        android:codes="102"
        android:keyLabel="f" />
    <Key
        android:codes="103"
        android:keyLabel="g" />
    <Key
        android:codes="104"
        android:keyLabel="h" />
    <Key
        android:codes="106"
        android:keyLabel="j" />
    <Key
        android:codes="107"
        android:keyLabel="k" />
    <Key
        android:codes="108"
        android:keyLabel="l" />

    <Key
        android:codes="45"
        android:keyEdgeFlags="right"
        android:keyLabel="-" />
</Row>
<Row>
    <Key
        android:codes="-1"
        android:isModifier="true"
        android:isSticky="true"
        android:keyEdgeFlags="left"
        android:keyIcon="@drawable/ic_keyboard_capital"
        android:keyWidth="10%p" />
    <Key
        android:codes="122"
        android:keyLabel="z" />
    <Key
        android:codes="120"
        android:keyLabel="x" />
    <Key
        android:codes="99"
        android:keyLabel="c" />
    <Key
        android:codes="118"
        android:keyLabel="v" />
    <Key
        android:codes="98"
        android:keyLabel="b" />
    <Key
        android:codes="110"
        android:keyLabel="n" />
    <Key
        android:codes="109"
        android:keyLabel="m" />
    <Key
        android:codes="96"
        android:keyLabel="'"
        android:keyEdgeFlags="right" />
</Row>
<Row android:rowEdgeFlags="bottom">
    <Key
        android:codes="123123"
        android:keyLabel="!#$"
        android:keyWidth="20.3%p" />
    <Key
        android:codes="32"
        android:keyIcon="@drawable/ic_keyboard_space_bar"
        android:keyWidth="48%p" />

    <Key
        android:codes="-5"
        android:isRepeatable="true"
        android:keyEdgeFlags="right"
        android:keyIcon="@drawable/ic_keyboard_delete"
        android:keyWidth="30.6%p" />
</Row>
```

Comment: Try to check this [tutorial](http://www.blackcj.com/blog/2016/03/30/building-a-custom-android-keyboard/) on how to build a custom android keyboard. You can learn here the step by step procedure on how to create it. It composes of sample code that you can copy. You can also check the links that are used in creating this custom keyboard. For more information, check this related [SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29285276/custom-keyboard-view-in-android).

Comment: @KENdi I did the same but I have to use the custom keyboard on AndroidTV, not on touchscreen devices. I am not able to focus on the custom keyboard using DPAD, If I use a mouse then I can click on the keyboard.

Comment: @GauravBarthwal did you find a solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

After doing a lot of research and not able to get my answer, I somehow managed to create a custom Keyboard using my own logic and with the help of **android.inputmethodservice.Keyboard** class. Below is my code to get Custom keyboar.

```
package com.gaurav.keyboard;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.inputmethodservice.Keyboard;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;


/**
 * Created by Gaurav on 29/12/16.
 * <p>
 * Utils class returns keyboard based on the requested Keyboard type 
   {KB_NUMERIC, KB_QWERTY, KB_EMAIL, KB_MONTH & KB_YEAR}.
 * <p>
 * Client has to implement {@link OnKeyClickListener} to get key click 
   event.
 * <p>
 * For multiple keyboards instantiate the class.
 */

public class KeyboardHelper {
public final String TAG = KeyboardHelper.class.getSimpleName();
private Context mContext;
private CustomKeyboardView keyboardView;

/**
 * CONSTANTS FOR KEYBOARD TYPES
 */
public static final int KB_NUMERIC = 1;
public static final int KB_QWERTY = 2;
public static final int KB_EMAIL = 3;
public static final int KB_MONTH = 4;
public static final int KB_YEAR = 5;
public static final int KB_SEARCH = 6;

/**
 * KEYBOARD KEY CODES
 */
public static final int KEY_CODE_SPACE = 32;
public static final int KEY_CODE_BACK_SPACE = -5;
public static final int KEY_CODE_SPECIAL_CHARACTER = 123123;
public static final int KEY_CODE_CLEAR = 123124;
public static final int KEY_CODE_CAPITAL_CASE = -1;
public static final int KEY_CODE_HOTMAIL_DOT_COM = 54321;
public static final int KEY_CODE_GMAIL_DOT_COM = 54320;
public static final int KEY_CODE_YAHOO_DOT_COM = 54319;
public static final int KEY_CODE_AT_THE_RATE = 85245;
public static final int KEY_CODE_DOT = 789789;
public static final int KEY_CODE_DOT_COM = 456654;
static final int KEY_CODE_EMPTY = 540;

/**
 * interface to get key event of keyboard
 * <p>
 * to get key code - clickedKey.codes[0]
 * NOTE :- All keys have single code.
 */
public interface OnKeyClickListener {
    void onKeyClick(Keyboard.Key clickedKey);
}

public KeyboardHelper(Context mContext, OnKeyClickListener onKeyClickListener) {
    this.mContext = mContext;
    keyboardView = new CustomKeyboardView(mContext, onKeyClickListener);
    keyboardView.setHasFixedSize(true);
}

/**
 * sets the selector for key
 *
 * @param selector - {@link Drawable}
 */
public void setKeySelector(Drawable selector) {
    if (selector != null)
        keyboardView.setKeyDrawable(selector);
}

/**
 * Returns the keyboard view based on the keyboard type
 *
 * @param mKeyboardType - int
 * @return - {@link RecyclerView}
 */
public RecyclerView requestKeyboard(int mKeyboardType) {
    switch (mKeyboardType) {
        case KB_NUMERIC:
            return keyboardView.loadKeyboard(KB_NUMERIC, new Keyboard(mContext, R.xml.keyboard_numeric));
        case KB_QWERTY:
            return keyboardView.loadKeyboard(KB_QWERTY, new Keyboard(mContext, R.xml.keyboard_qwerty));
        case KB_EMAIL:
            return keyboardView.loadKeyboard(KB_EMAIL, new Keyboard(mContext, R.xml.keyboard_email));
        case KB_MONTH:
            return keyboardView.loadKeyboard(KB_MONTH, new Keyboard(mContext, R.xml.keyboard_month));
        case KB_YEAR:
            return keyboardView.loadKeyboard(KB_YEAR, new Keyboard(mContext, R.xml.keyboard_month));
        case KB_SEARCH:
            return keyboardView.loadKeyboard(KB_SEARCH, new Keyboard(mContext, R.xml.keyboard_search));
        default:
            return keyboardView.loadKeyboard(KB_QWERTY, new Keyboard(mContext, R.xml.keyboard_qwerty));
    }
}
```

}

**CustomKeyboardView** returns a fully fledged Keyboard wrapped in RecyclerView. Number of keys are fixed though I hardcoded some values in **initializeRows()**.

```
package com.gaurav.keyboard;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.inputmethodservice.Keyboard;
import android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;

import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.List;

/**
 * Created by Gaurav on 21/2/17.
 * This class extends {@link RecyclerView} and returns Keyboard layout
 */
class CustomKeyboardView extends RecyclerView {
    private final String TAG = CustomKeyboardView.class.getSimpleName();

private Context mContext;
private Resources resources;

private int ROWS;

private LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager;

private List<Keyboard.Key> mKeys;
private List<Keyboard.Key> mModifierKeys;
private int keyboardType;
private int startIndex;
private int endIndex;
int[] years = new int[3];
private int currentYear;

private KeyboardAdapter keyboardAdapter;

private KeyboardHelper.OnKeyClickListener onKeyClickListener;
private boolean areKeysCapital = false;
private boolean areKeysSpecial = false;

private Drawable keyDrawable;

private boolean isKeyPressed = false;

private List<Keyboard.Key> mSpecialKeys;
private List<Keyboard.Key> mCharKeys;

CustomKeyboardView(Context context, KeyboardHelper.OnKeyClickListener mCallBack) {
    super(context);
    mContext = context;
    resources = getResources();

    linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(mContext, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false);

    try {
        onKeyClickListener = mCallBack;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.getMessage();
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
}

/**
 * sets drawable for key layout
 *
 * @param keyDrawable - {@link Drawable}
 */
void setKeyDrawable(Drawable keyDrawable) {
    this.keyDrawable = keyDrawable;
}

/**
 * Returns {@link CustomKeyboardView} based on the keyboard type
 * @param keyboardType - requested keyboard
 * @param keyboard     - {@link Keyboard} needs to be loaded
 * @return - {@link CustomKeyboardView}
 */
CustomKeyboardView loadKeyboard(int keyboardType, Keyboard keyboard) {
    this.keyboardType = keyboardType;
    mKeys = keyboard.getKeys();
    if (keyboardType == KeyboardHelper.KB_YEAR) {
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
        currentYear = calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    }
    initializeRows();
    keyboardAdapter = new KeyboardAdapter(mContext);
    setAdapter(keyboardAdapter);
    return this;
}

/**
 * initializes rows of the keyboard's rows and columns
 * numeric, month and year keyboard will have 4 rows, qwerty keyboard has 6 rows and email keyboard has 6 rows
 */
private void initializeRows() {
    switch (keyboardType) {
        case KeyboardHelper.KB_NUMERIC:
            startIndex = 0;
            endIndex = 3;
            ROWS = 4;
            break;
        case KeyboardHelper.KB_QWERTY:
            startIndex = 0;
            endIndex = 10;
            ROWS = 5;
            mSpecialKeys = new Keyboard(mContext, R.xml.special_character_keys).getKeys();
            mCharKeys = new Keyboard(mContext, R.xml.character_keys).getKeys();
            break;
        case KeyboardHelper.KB_EMAIL:
            startIndex = 0;
            endIndex = 10;
            ROWS = 6;
            mSpecialKeys = new Keyboard(mContext, R.xml.special_character_keys).getKeys();
            mCharKeys = new Keyboard(mContext, R.xml.character_keys).getKeys();
            break;
        case KeyboardHelper.KB_MONTH:
            startIndex = 0;
            endIndex = 3;
            ROWS = 4;
            break;
        case KeyboardHelper.KB_YEAR:
            startIndex = 0;
            endIndex = 3;
            ROWS = 4;
            break;
        case KeyboardHelper.KB_SEARCH:
            startIndex = 0;
            endIndex = 19;
            ROWS = 3;
            break;
    }
}

/**
 * gets keys for the given positioned row
 * NOTE - calculations have been done based on keys in each rows.
 * @param position - row position
 * @return - List of {@link android.inputmethodservice.Keyboard.Key}
 */
private List<Keyboard.Key> getRowKeys(int position) {
    List<Keyboard.Key> rowKeys = null;
    switch (keyboardType) {
        case KeyboardHelper.KB_NUMERIC:
            if (position < 3)
                rowKeys = mKeys.subList(startIndex, endIndex);
            else
                rowKeys = mKeys.subList(startIndex, mKeys.size());
            startIndex = endIndex;
            endIndex = endIndex + 3;
            break;
        case KeyboardHelper.KB_QWERTY:
            if (position < 3)
                rowKeys = mKeys.subList(startIndex, endIndex);
            else if (position == 3)
                rowKeys = mKeys.subList(30, 39);
            else if (position == 4)
                rowKeys = mKeys.subList(39, mKeys.size());
            startIndex = endIndex;
            endIndex = endIndex + 10;
            break;
        case KeyboardHelper.KB_EMAIL:
            if (position < 3)
                rowKeys = mKeys.subList(startIndex, endIndex);
            else if (position == 3)
                rowKeys = mKeys.subList(30, 39);
            else if (position == 4)
                rowKeys = mKeys.subList(39, 42);
            else if (position == 5)
                rowKeys = mKeys.subList(42, mKeys.size());
            startIndex = endIndex;
            endIndex = endIndex + 10;
            break;
        case KeyboardHelper.KB_MONTH:
            rowKeys = mKeys.subList(startIndex, endIndex);
            startIndex = endIndex;
            endIndex = endIndex + 3;
            break;
        case KeyboardHelper.KB_YEAR:
            rowKeys = mKeys.subList(startIndex, endIndex);
            startIndex = endIndex;
            endIndex = endIndex + 3;
            for (int i = 0; i < years.length; i++) {
                years[i] = currentYear++;
            }
            break;
        case KeyboardHelper.KB_SEARCH:
            rowKeys = mKeys.subList(startIndex, endIndex);
            startIndex = endIndex;
            endIndex = endIndex + 19;
            if (position == 1)
                endIndex = mKeys.size();
            break;
    }
    return rowKeys;
}

/**
 * Adapter for the keyboard
 * It helps to set each row
 */
private class KeyboardAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {

    private final Context mContext;

    KeyboardAdapter(Context mContext) {
        this.mContext = mContext;
    }

    class KeyboardViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        private RecyclerView keyboardRow;

        KeyboardViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            keyboardRow = (RecyclerView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.keyboardRow);
            keyboardRow.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(mContext, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false));
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return ROWS;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        KeyboardViewHolder _holder = (KeyboardViewHolder) holder;

        _holder.keyboardRow.setAdapter(new KeyAdapter(getRowKeys(position)));

    }

    @Override
    public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.layout_keyboard_row, parent, false);

        return new KeyboardViewHolder(v);
    }
}

/**
 * Adapter for row key
 */
private class KeyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {
    private List<Keyboard.Key> rowKeys;

    KeyAdapter(List<Keyboard.Key> rowKeys) {
        this.rowKeys = rowKeys;
    }

    class KeyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        private AppCompatImageView keyIcon;
        private KeyTextView keyLabel, keySupportLabel;
        private RelativeLayout key_layout;

        KeyViewHolder(final View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            key_layout = (RelativeLayout) itemView.findViewById(R.id.key_layout);
            keyIcon = (AppCompatImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.keyIcon);
            keyLabel = (KeyTextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.keyLabel);
            keySupportLabel = (KeyTextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.keySupportLabel);

            /*
             * if user has defined keyDrawable then no need to apply default animations
             */
            if (keyDrawable == null) {
                itemView.setOnKeyListener(new OnKeyListener() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean onKey(View view, int i, KeyEvent keyEvent) {
                        if (keyEvent.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_CENTER) {
                            Keyboard.Key clickedKey = rowKeys.get(getAdapterPosition());
                            if(keyEvent.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                                itemView.setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.key_press_gradient));
                                clickedKey.label = keyLabel.getText();
                                if (clickedKey.modifier) {
                                    if(clickedKey.codes[0] == KeyboardHelper.KEY_CODE_CAPITAL_CASE)
                                        toggleKeyCase();
                                    else if(clickedKey.codes[0] == KeyboardHelper.KEY_CODE_SPECIAL_CHARACTER)
                                        toggleSpecialCase(keyLabel);
                                } else {
                                    if (onKeyClickListener != null) {
                                        onKeyClickListener.onKeyClick(clickedKey);
                                    }
                                }
                            }else {
                                if((keyEvent.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_UP) && clickedKey.codes[0] == KeyboardHelper.KEY_CODE_BACK_SPACE) {
                                    if (onKeyClickListener != null) {
                                        onKeyClickListener.onKeyClick(clickedKey);
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        } else
                            itemView.setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.tv_key_board_key_background));
                        return false;
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return rowKeys.size();
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        KeyViewHolder _holder = (KeyViewHolder) holder;
        _holder.itemView.setFocusable(true);
        _holder.itemView.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
        _holder.itemView.setVisibility(VISIBLE);
        Keyboard.Key mKey = rowKeys.get(position);
        if (mKey.icon != null) {
            _holder.keyIcon.setBackgroundDrawable(mKey.icon);
            _holder.keyIcon.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        } else {
            if (keyboardType == KeyboardHelper.KB_YEAR)
                _holder.keyLabel.setText("" + years[position]);
            else
                _holder.keyLabel.setText(mKey.label);
            _holder.keyIcon.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }

        /*
         * for EMAIL keyboard - gmail, hotmail and yahoo keys label text size has to be changed
         */
        if (keyboardType == KeyboardHelper.KB_EMAIL) {
            int keyCode = mKey.codes[0];
            if (keyCode == KeyboardHelper.KEY_CODE_GMAIL_DOT_COM
                    || keyCode == KeyboardHelper.KEY_CODE_YAHOO_DOT_COM
                    || keyCode == KeyboardHelper.KEY_CODE_HOTMAIL_DOT_COM) {
                _holder.keyLabel.setTextSize(resources.getDimension(R.dimen.key_label_size));
            }
        } else if (keyboardType == KeyboardHelper.KB_MONTH) {
            _holder.keySupportLabel.setText(mKey.text);
            _holder.keySupportLabel.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        } else if(keyboardType == KeyboardHelper.KB_SEARCH && mKey.codes[0] == KeyboardHelper.KEY_CODE_EMPTY) {
            _holder.itemView.setFocusable(false);
            _holder.itemView.setFocusableInTouchMode(false);
            _holder.itemView.setVisibility(INVISIBLE);
        }

        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(mKey.width, mKey.height);
        layoutParams.setMargins(mKey.gap, mKey.gap, mKey.gap, mKey.gap);
        _holder.key_layout.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);

        if (keyDrawable != null) {
            _holder.key_layout.setBackground(keyDrawable);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.layout_key, parent, false);

        return new KeyViewHolder(v);
    }
}

/**
 * toggles key case
 * NOTE - only qwerty and email keyboard has change case key and 1,2 and 3'rows will be going to update
 */
private void toggleKeyCase() {
    try {
        if (keyboardAdapter != null) {
            for (int i = 1; i < 4; i++) {
                RecyclerView keyboardRow = (RecyclerView) linearLayoutManager.getChildAt(i);
                LinearLayoutManager keyBoardLayoutManager = (LinearLayoutManager) keyboardRow.getLayoutManager();
                for (int j = 0; j < keyBoardLayoutManager.getItemCount(); j++) {
                    View keyView = keyBoardLayoutManager.getChildAt(j);
                    KeyTextView yuppTextView = (KeyTextView) keyView.findViewById(R.id.keyLabel);
                    if (!areKeysCapital) {
                        yuppTextView.setText(yuppTextView.getText().toString().toUpperCase());
                    } else {
                        yuppTextView.setText(yuppTextView.getText().toString().toLowerCase());
                    }
                }
            }
            areKeysCapital = !areKeysCapital;
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

/**
 * switch keyboard case between special character and alphabet
 * Special characters are available only for KB_QWERTY and KB_EMAIL.
 * only top 4 rows are going to be changed
 */
private void toggleSpecialCase(KeyTextView keyLabel) {
    try {
        if (keyboardAdapter != null
                && mSpecialKeys != null
                && (keyboardType == KeyboardHelper.KB_EMAIL || keyboardType == KeyboardHelper.KB_QWERTY)) {
            startIndex = 0;
            endIndex = 10;
            if(areKeysSpecial) {
                keyLabel.setText("!#$");
                for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
                    RecyclerView keyboardRow = (RecyclerView) linearLayoutManager.getChildAt(i);
                    LinearLayoutManager keyBoardLayoutManager = (LinearLayoutManager) keyboardRow.getLayoutManager();
                    List<Keyboard.Key> rowKeys = mCharKeys.subList(startIndex, endIndex);
                    for (int j = 0; j < keyBoardLayoutManager.getItemCount(); j++) {
                        View keyView = keyBoardLayoutManager.getChildAt(j);
                        KeyTextView yuppTextView = (KeyTextView) keyView.findViewById(R.id.keyLabel);
                        yuppTextView.setText(rowKeys.get(j).label);
                    }
                    startIndex = endIndex;
                    if(i == 2)
                        endIndex = mSpecialKeys.size();
                    else
                        endIndex = endIndex + 10;
                }
                areKeysSpecial = false;
            }else if(!areKeysSpecial) {
                keyLabel.setText("abc");
                for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
                    RecyclerView keyboardRow = (RecyclerView) linearLayoutManager.getChildAt(i);
                    LinearLayoutManager keyBoardLayoutManager = (LinearLayoutManager) keyboardRow.getLayoutManager();
                    List<Keyboard.Key> rowKeys = mSpecialKeys.subList(startIndex, endIndex);
                    for (int j = 0; j < keyBoardLayoutManager.getItemCount(); j++) {

                        View keyView = keyBoardLayoutManager.getChildAt(j);
                        KeyTextView yuppTextView = (KeyTextView) keyView.findViewById(R.id.keyLabel);
                        if (!areKeysSpecial) {
                            yuppTextView.setText(rowKeys.get(j).label);
                        } else {
                            yuppTextView.setText(yuppTextView.getText().toString().toLowerCase());
                        }
                    }
                    startIndex = endIndex;
                    if(i == 2)
                        endIndex = mSpecialKeys.size();
                    else
                        endIndex = endIndex + 10;
                }
                areKeysSpecial = true;
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}

A sample of keyboard_email.xml. Provide key height, width, and gaps.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Keyboard xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:horizontalGap="@dimen/key_gap"
android:keyHeight="@dimen/key_email_default_height"
android:keyWidth="@dimen/key_email_default_width"
android:verticalGap="@dimen/key_gap">
<Row>
    <Key
        android:codes="49"
        android:keyEdgeFlags="left"
        android:keyLabel="1" />
    <Key
        android:codes="50"
        android:keyLabel="2" />
    <Key
        android:codes="51"
        android:keyLabel="3" />
    <Key
        android:codes="52"
        android:keyLabel="4" />
    <Key
        android:codes="53"
        android:keyLabel="5" />
    <Key
        android:codes="54"
        android:keyLabel="6" />
    <Key
        android:codes="55"
        android:keyLabel="7" />
    <Key
        android:codes="56"
        android:keyLabel="8" />
    <Key
        android:codes="57"
        android:keyLabel="9" />
    <Key
        android:codes="48"
        android:keyEdgeFlags="right"
        android:keyLabel="0" />
</Row>
<Row>
    <Key
        android:codes="113"
        android:keyEdgeFlags="left"
        android:keyLabel="q" />
    <Key
        android:codes="119"
        android:keyLabel="w" />
    <Key
        android:codes="101"
        android:keyLabel="e" />
    <Key
        android:codes="114"
        android:keyLabel="r" />
    <Key
        android:codes="116"
        android:keyLabel="t" />
    <Key
        android:codes="121"
        android:keyLabel="y" />
    <Key
        android:codes="117"
        android:keyLabel="u" />
    <Key
        android:codes="105"
        android:keyLabel="i" />
    <Key
        android:codes="111"
        android:keyLabel="o" />
    <Key
        android:codes="112"
        android:keyEdgeFlags="right"
        android:keyLabel="p" />
</Row>
<Row>
    <Key
        android:codes="97"
        android:keyEdgeFlags="left"
        android:keyLabel="a" />
    <Key
        android:codes="115"
        android:keyLabel="s" />
    <Key
        android:codes="100"
        android:keyLabel="d" />
    <Key
        android:codes="102"
        android:keyLabel="f" />
    <Key
        android:codes="103"
        android:keyLabel="g" />
    <Key
        android:codes="104"
        android:keyLabel="h" />
    <Key
        android:codes="106"
        android:keyLabel="j" />
    <Key
        android:codes="107"
        android:keyLabel="k" />
    <Key
        android:codes="108"
        android:keyLabel="l" />

    <Key
        android:codes="45"
        android:keyEdgeFlags="right"
        android:keyLabel="-" />
</Row>
<Row>
    <Key
        android:codes="-1"
        android:isModifier="true"
        android:isSticky="true"
        android:keyEdgeFlags="left"
        android:keyIcon="@drawable/ic_keyboard_capital"
        android:keyWidth="@dimen/key_capital_case_width" />

    <Key
        android:codes="122"
        android:keyLabel="z" />
    <Key
        android:codes="120"
        android:keyLabel="x" />
    <Key
        android:codes="99"
        android:keyLabel="c" />
    <Key
        android:codes="118"
        android:keyLabel="v" />
    <Key
        android:codes="98"
        android:keyLabel="b" />
    <Key
        android:codes="110"
        android:keyLabel="n" />
    <Key
        android:codes="109"
        android:keyLabel="m" />
    <Key
        android:codes="96"
        android:keyEdgeFlags="right"
        android:keyLabel="'" />
</Row>
<Row>
    <Key
        android:codes="54321"
        android:isRepeatable="true"
        android:keyEdgeFlags="left"
        android:keyHeight="@dimen/key_email_domain_height"
        android:keyLabel="@string/hotmail.com"
        android:keyWidth="@dimen/key_email_domain_width" />
    <Key
        android:codes="54320"
        android:isRepeatable="true"
        android:keyHeight="@dimen/key_email_domain_height"
        android:keyLabel="@string/gmail.com"
        android:keyWidth="@dimen/key_email_domain_width" />
    <Key
        android:codes="54319"
        android:isRepeatable="true"
        android:keyEdgeFlags="right"
        android:keyHeight="@dimen/key_email_domain_height"
        android:keyLabel="@string/yahoo.com"
        android:keyWidth="@dimen/key_email_domain_width" />
</Row>
<Row android:rowEdgeFlags="bottom">
    <Key
        android:codes="123123"
        android:keyEdgeFlags="left"
        android:isModifier="true"
        android:isSticky="true"
        android:keyLabel="!#$"
        android:keyWidth="@dimen/key_special_char_width" />

    <Key
        android:codes="85245"
        android:keyLabel="\@"
        android:keyWidth="@dimen/key_special_char_width" />

    <Key
        android:codes="789789"
        android:keyLabel="." />

    <Key
        android:codes="456654"
        android:keyLabel=".com"
        android:keyWidth="@dimen/key_special_char_width" />

    <Key
        android:codes="-5"
        android:isRepeatable="true"
        android:keyEdgeFlags="right"
        android:keyIcon="@drawable/ic_keyboard_delete"
        android:keyWidth="@dimen/key_qwerty_delete_width" />
</Row>
</Keyboard>
```

Implementation-

```
RecyclerView qwertyKeyboard = new KeyboardHelper(mActivity, PaymentInfoFragment.this).requestKeyboard(KeyboardHelper.KB_QWERTY);
```

**Implement KeyboardHelper.OnKeyClickListener to get click event.**

This code is fine for my requirement.

Comment: RecyclerView qwertyKeyboard = new KeyboardHelper(mActivity, PaymentInfoFragment.this).requestKeyboard(KeyboardHelper.KB_QWERTY);
qwertyKeyboard.requestFocus();

Comment: Did you found any way using the key and keyboard view itself rather than recycler view?